# Redirect without changing Url htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm wondering if this is possible - I have projects structured like:

```
www.mydomain.com points to MyFolder on server. In MyFolder i have 3 App Folders eg MyFolder/App1, MyFolder/App2..
```

Each of these are 3 different web applications. Url of domain is www.mydomain.com
Is it possible, that, when url user go to mydomain.com, it automatically redirect to mydomain.com/App1 but without url change visible to user (in browser it will still be mydomain.com)?
I can not point domain to MyFolder/App1 because that way app2 is not accessible.
My solution is that app1 becomes a root which contains app2,app3 etc folder but thats just to messy
edit: question clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use this code here.

```
RewriteEngine on
#ignore App1 and App2 and interally Rewrite to /App
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(App1|App2) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /App/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Should I put this into htaccess in my root folder or in each subfolders?

Comment: In your root. It won't work in each folder like this.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to achieve what i wanted with this code:
`RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(App) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /App/$1 [L]
`
Does this code interprent like this: If there's no App in url an there's no valid target for url (eg it's not www.mydomain.com/Folder2 - where folder2 holds some other application) redirect to www.mydomain.com/App ?
I'm really grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do it in your .htaccess file like this (untested code):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/App
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/App1 [P]
```

Comment: Should I put this into htaccess in my root folder or in each subfolders?